# Read variables from other Perl programs that are not in a package

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program that wants to run Perl code in bunch of other files and grab all of the variables that were set in each one.  Under normal circumstances these other files would be in their own pages, for example `package foo` inside of foo.pm. Then I'd just `use foo`, then nose around in `%foo::` to see what was defined.  My challenge is that the other files do not contain a `package` declaration and cannot be modified to do so.

How can a Perl program run code in other Perl files that do not specify a `package` and grab the variables and values set by them?

Additional constraints:

- Must work in Perl 5.10.1 and later. All core modules as of 5.10.1 are available.
- Must work on Linux.  (I'm currently using Red Hat 6, but the exact distribution may change.)
- I would like to minimize the number of dependencies this project has.  I'm open to adding one or two additional dependencies.
- I'll be processing multiple files.  It's necessary that the other files not pollute the parent's symbols, nor the symbols of other files.  The goal is to protect against accidental damage; I can safely assume the other files are not malicious. The other files will not try to modify other packages, although they may `use` modules themselves.  I'm willing to live with other side effects caused by running the other file's code.

(I re-wrote this question to be more focused. The first few comments are addressing the previous version.)

Comment: It used to be that *all* Perl programmers wrote templating and ORM libraries. Nowadays, this is very likely re-inventing the wheel. Start with who will be editing/managing the template data, and work backwards to determine the technology and how those people will access the content in enough detail to do their job. You may be better off with one of the more sophisticated templating libraries, and then using a database for the managed data (`$author` and `$title` in your example).

Comment: I certainly wrote my own templating engine. :-) Later I became wise and moved to Template Toolkit.
There is a good chance that I'll be handing this off to someone who is not fluent in Perl or whatever else I use, but will be expected to extend it, fix it, or even outright replace it. Said person may have nothing other than a baseline Linux system. So the fewer moving parts the better. On the upside, the users will all be programmers, so I can get away with more (ex Perl input files ).

My real goal: don't make the next guy as angry as I was when I got it. :-)

Comment: The constraint on not modifying the original files is limited to the original files in the original locations. I can modify the other files in memory and save modified versions in a different location. I do need to keep using the original versions each time I run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the obligatory: There **MUST** be a better way to do what you want.

If you're determined to go this route, your original approach is easily extended.  Just evaluate each file (using `do`) inside a fresh package with a constructed name that is unlikely to collide with any other package used in your program, then examine that package's symbol table afterward.  In this example I name the packages `__Scratch__::__1`, `__Scratch__::__2`, etc.

```
my $index = 0;

for my $file (@files) {
    my $pkg  = sprintf '__Scratch__::__%d', ++$index;
    my $code = "package $pkg; do \$file; %$pkg\::";
    my %symbol_table = eval $code;
    # add error checking to taste...
    print "Symbols defined after evaluating $file: ",
        join(', ', keys %symbol_table), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't modify the files, but can you modify the in-memory contents of the files?

For example, if `/path/to/somefile.pm` is one of your non-module files, you could do something like

```
open my $pm, "<", /path/to/somefile.pm or die;
my @lines = <$pm>;
eval(join("\n","package somefile;", @lines, "1;"));

# now you could do something like
somefile::afunction("hello");
```

And now you've got it loaded in memory like a proper package. (OK, not a *proper* package.)