# Access __DATA__ from a package created in eval("string") in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm creating a package with a dynamic name and  a `__DATA__` section in `eval("")`.  Can i access the `__DATA__`, and if so how?

Here is what I have so far.  I would not expect the code to die on the last line, but it does.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

$packname = "testpackage";

eval(<<END);
package $packname;
\$foo='bar';
__DATA__
Some data lives here
END

# Prints "bar" as expected:
$glob = ${$packname."::"}{foo};
print "${$glob}\n"  if defined ${ *{$glob}{SCALAR} };

# Dies, which is not expected
$glob = ${$packname."::"}{DATA};
die "No DATA symbol" if not defined $glob;
```

If it didn't die, I'd hope to be able to say something like

```
$data = <${$packname."::"}{DATA}>;
```

but clearly that's not going to work.

Even this

```
my $body = <testpackage::DATA>;
```

fails with "readline() on unopened filehandle DATA".  Even if it it worked, it wouldn't solve my problem, since I don't know the package name up front.

In the real program, the string passed to `eval("")` comes from an external source. (One that I trust.  Me, just with a different hat on.)  Obviously since I have the string I used, I could manually grovel around for `__DATA__` and get what I want.  But it would be nice if I could just take advantage of .

(Why in the world am I doing this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085621/how-to-use-perl-as-data-file-language  Answers in the form "Down this road lies madness, turn back!" are might be a better fit over there. Edited to add: the linked question has been massively overhauled. In short: I'm trying to use simple Perl programs as input files to a templating system.)

Comment: Occurs to me that DATA is probably the handle to the file/stdin Perl read. No file/stream, therefore no DATA. If true, the answer is "Not possible using <DATA>, dig it out yourself".  I'd accept an answer showing this theory is correct.

Comment: interesting Question. Did you tried [`Data::Package`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Package) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even this doesn't work:

```
    perl -e 'package Foo;
    print <Foo::DATA>;
    __DATA__
    FOO'
```

So the `DATA` filehandle is only opened when a proper input stream is parsed. Down this road lies madness, of course, but if this is really the way you want to go, you can still make it work by arranging to read your input from a file:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

$packname = "testpackage";

use lib "/tmp";
open TMP,  ">", "/tmp/tempcode.pm";

print TMP <<END;
package $packname;
\$foo='bar';
__DATA__
Some data lives here
END

close TMP;
require tempcode;
unlink "/tmp/tempcode.pm";
eval "print <$packname" . "::DATA>";
```